# 「メインスレッドでの同期XMLHttpRequestは、エンドユーザーエクスペリエンスに悪影響を与えるため、非推奨です」の警告表示を解消したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

以下の警告が出ます。解決方法を教えてください！

**警告メッセージ:**

```
jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

[image]

**現状のコード:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Microsoft Translator テキスト API サンプル</h1>
  <h2>フォームの入力データを英語に翻訳します。</h2>

  <div id="japanese"></div>

  <input type="text" id="inText" oninput="inputText()" placeholder="入力してください">
  <div id="endMsg">入力完了と判定しました<br>入力：</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict"

      var gTimer; 
      function inputText(){
        var wObj    = document.getElementById("endMsg");
        wObj.innerHTML = '入力中です';
        wObj.className = 'defStyle runStyle';
        if(gTimer){clearTimeout(gTimer);}
        gTimer = setTimeout(inputEnd, 700);
      }

      function inputEnd(){

        var wObj    = document.getElementById("endMsg");
        wObj.innerHTML = '入力完了と判定しました<br>入力：'+document.getElementById("inText").value;
        wObj.className = 'defStyle endStyle';

        const now = new Date();
        const nowtime = now.getTime();

        const getToken = function() {
          const defer = $.Deferred();
      
          const arr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tdata"));
    
          if (arr === null || arr.time + 1000 * 60 * 8 < nowtime) {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
              type: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/jwt',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'キー',
              },
              async: false,
            }).done(function(data) {
    
              const datalist = {
                time: nowtime,
                token: data,
              }
              sessionStorage.setItem('tdata', JSON.stringify(datalist));
            });
          }
    
          const arr2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tdata"));
          const token = arr2.token;
          defer.resolve(token);
          return defer.promise();
        };
    
        $.when(getToken()).done(function(token) {
          const key = 'Bearer ' + token;
          const text = $("#inText").val();
          const response = $.ajax({
              url: 'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate',
              type: 'GET',
              data: {
                'appid': key,
                'Accept': 'application/xml',
                'text': text,
                'to': 'en',
              },
              async: false,
            })
          const data = response.responseText;
          const translation = data.replace(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/g, '');
          $("#japanese").text(translation);
    
        })
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ちなみに、jQuery.ajaxのオプションでasync: falseとしている理由はありますか？

Comment: この質問の解決方法とは、なんでもいいので警告メッセージを非表示にしたい　なのか、警告メッセージについて理解して対処する　なのかどちらでしょう。

Comment: 警告の同期型呼び出しもそうですが、実はそれ以前に呼び出しているサービス自身が非推奨ではありませんか？ [Translator V2 から V3 への移行](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/translator/migrate-to-v3) `注意 V2 は、2018 年 4 月 30 日に非推奨となりました。... V2 は 2021 年 5 月 24 日に廃止される予定です。` この注意記述どおりではなくまだ廃止されていないのかもしれませんが。こちらが現在の方法でしょうか？ [Translator 3.0:Translate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate)

Comment: async:trueで解決しました